# Viewing an app while working on another app underneath

Tags: windows-10

I would like to be able to View the kindle desktop app while working in R. [image]

As you can see, R is open underneath the kindle app. Now when I go to type in R the kindle app becomes no longer visible. I realise this is standard behaviour for overlapping panes. I also realise that if I minimise R so it takes up half the screen I can work in R while being able to view the kindle app. The problem is that R has four panes and they all become too small if I minimise the window too much.

My question is, **is there *any* way to keep one app open *underneath* another in windows 10?**

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t use side-by-side view? No; How an application deals with being the non-active Window is primarily up to the author of the application.

Comment: You can have open apps underneath each other. Just use the taskbar to bring the desired app to the front.

Comment: Search Google for "Windows always on top". There are several utilities that can help with this problem.